# Selenium(c# console) : I want to quit all my webdrivers and restart them periodically

Tags: c#, selenium, timer, console, webdriver

I'm not good at English so I don't know whether I wrote properly.

I studied programming for a week.

I want to quit all my webdrivers and restart every two hours. But I failed.

---

version 1

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(OnTimer, driver, 7200000, Timeout.Infinite);

    do {
    //Automation Program
    }while(true)

    driver.Quit();
}
static void OnTimer(Object driver)
{
    driver.Quit();
    /*
    Restart Process/Application code.
    Not made yet. Because driver.Quit() didn't work.
    */
}
```

---

version 2

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(OnTimer, "test", 1000, 7200000);
}
static void OnTimer(Object state)
{
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    do {
    //Automation Program
    }while(true)

    driver.Quit();
}
```

---

The reason I failed was that I tried to control WebDriver with OnTimer.

Is there a good way to quit webdriver and restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all : You must define IWebDriver driver global not private.

secound : you forgot driver.close() command.

third : you must do your process in thread and dont your timer in another thread ;

```
IWebDriver driver;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    myTimer .Elapsed+=new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    myTimer .Interval=7200000;
    myTimer .Enabled=true;

    Thread th=new Thread(new ThreadStart(dosomething));
            th.Start();
}
 private static void dosomething()
        {
            // do something (works)
        }
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
     driver.Close();
    driver.Quit();
    driver.Dispose();
 }
```

Comment: It was a perfect solution. I forgot to define as a global. thanks!